# What's wrong with this simple Safari Extension code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm creating a Safari extension that will stay in Safari's menubar, and upon being clicked, it will open all links containing a certain string. However, it's not working.

This is what my extension builder screen looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSBRw.png

I don't have any external scripts set as I have the script in my HTML file, because I only want it to run when clicked.

And I have a global.html page with the following code in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            safari.application.addEventListener("comnand", performCommand, false);

            Function performCommand(event) {  
                if (event.command == "open-designs") {  
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('a[href*="/Create/DesignProduct.aspx?"]').each(function() {
                            window.open($(this).attr('href'),'_blank');
                        });
                    });
                }  
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Should this not work? I'm allowed to mix jQuery and JS write, as jQuery is JS? And isn't that how I'd target the links?

Comment: Looks like this code is **trying** to open a new tab for every `<a>` tag referencing `DesignProduct.aspx`... What exactly is it **supposed** to do?

Comment: That's exactly what it's trying to do. I want it to find every href on the page containing a specific string, and open all those in new tabs.

Comment: I don't think "comnand" is a valid event to which you can subscribe. Check the spelling mistake there. Also, JS is case sensitive. "Function" should be "function" with a lower-case "f."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your extensions Global page does not have direct access to the currently loaded page's DOM. To be able to achieve what you need, you'll have to use an [Injected Script](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html) and use the [messaging proxy to talk to the page](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingExtensionToolbars/AddingExtensionToolbars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH5-SW7).

For instance, your global would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);
            });

            function performCommand(event) {  
                if (event.command == "open-designs") { 
                    safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("open-designs", "all");
                }  
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then, in Extension Builder, you'd need to add two "Start Scripts", one is jquery, the other, a new file that gets loaded into the page and looks similar to this:

```
function extensionname_openAll(event)
{
    if (event.name == 'open-designs')
    {
        $('a[href*="/Create/DesignProduct.aspx?"]').each(function(index,elem) {
            window.open($(elem).attr('href'),'_blank');
        });
    }
}
safari.self.addEventListener("message", extensionname_openAll, true);
```

Comment: Even with that code it doesn't appear to work. Here's what one of the a tags would look like that I'd want to match. `<a id="cphMain_dlStoreProduct_hlDesign_1" class="SelHyperLink" href="/Create/DesignProduct.aspx?StoreProductId=31906060&amp;SectionCode=@ww131">Design</a>` But I still can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: And, foolish error on my part. It works perfectly now, thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you got it going in the end. Was your "foolish error" on the page or in the script?

Comment: I'd also like to thank you a lot Alex, as I got stuck here as well and it worked great! :)

Answer (score 3):

1. One clear thing I'm seeing is that your `$(document).ready()` function is located within another function.  This essentially alleviates the need for a `$(document).ready()` provided you only call that function once the DOM and jQuery are fully loaded.

   Rearrange your code to only add the event listener once the DOM and jQuery are loaded.  **That** is what you use the `$(document).ready()` callback for.
2. In addition there is one more issue I see with the callback function for  `.each()`.  That function needs to handle two parameters the index and the element that it references. A call to `each()`  iterates over a collection of elements.  For each element entering the callback function, its index is passed as a parameter and also the element itself that is located at that index.  Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for more info.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);
 console.log("Document is ready to go!");
});

function performCommand(event) {  
  console.log("event recieved");
  if (event.command == "open-designs") {     
    console.log("got 'open-designs' event");
    $('a[href*="/Create/DesignProduct.aspx?"]').each(function(index,elem) {
      console.log("opening window", index, elem);
      window.open($(elem).attr('href'),'_blank');
    });
  }  
}
```

You use the `$(document).ready()` callback as an indication that your DOM is ready and jQuery has been initialized.  Once you know everything is ready, you can setup your event listener.
The function `performCommand()` can not be called before the listener is added (unless there is some other reference to it).

Comment: With each, what are the index and elements representing? That's confusing me.

Comment: @dou, I've made an edit to try clarify this.  If you need more explanation don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, all the edits are evidently representing that, I really appreciate it. However, even understanding each, the code does still not seem to be working. Is my gathering of the selector actually right?

Comment: This would be a perfect time to use some `console.log()`'s or some `alert()`'s to see where exactly the code is breaking... see my edits...

Comment: @DougSmith: Have you corrected the spelling mistake on "command" yet? Your code might not be doing anything because you haven't actually subscribed to any valid events yet.

Comment: I fixed both, with the new code available here http://cl.ly/2O2E2O191q2j2a0G3K3k and still nothing.

Comment: Does it reach the `$(document).ready()` callback?  Have you taken my advice with regard to the logging?

Comment: I assume it reaches document.ready as if I add alert("HELLO!"); as the first line in the if statement it will alert me when I click on the extension button, so I assume it's adding the event listener correctly. However if I add it in the "each loop" it does not do anything, which obviously leads me to believe something is wrong with my each code or my selection.

Comment: I would think, as if I put alert("HELLO!"); as the first line in the if statement block it alerts me when I click the extension button.

Comment: How about if you alert `$('a[href*="/Create/DesignProduct.aspx?"]')`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11167/discussion-between-lix-and-doug-smith)

Comment: @Lix I am stuck on same thing, can you guys tell me what was the problem, for me as well it's not working

Comment: @Lix it would help me a lot. for me       console.log("opening window", index, elem); log message is not printing

Comment: @DougSmith can you help me to tell what was wrong in your code, my attempt is working here http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TzUN3/    but not in global.html file